# Reflect function eliminate mixing of switch and if statement in a function

Tags: go, switch-statement

This question is mainly just about cosmetics, this code does it's intended job, but I would love to be able to use the `switch` statement in both cases instead of mixing `if` and `switch`.

```
func fieldValue(field reflect.Value) string {
    format := "%v"
    if stringer, ok := field.Interface().(strfmt.DateTime); ok {
        return fmt.Sprintf(format, stringer.String())
    }
    switch field.Kind() {
    case reflect.Ptr:
        if field.IsNil() {
            return "<nil>"
        }
        field = field.Elem()
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(format, field.Interface())
}
```

Comment: You can't use both type assertions and boolean expressions in a single switch statement.

Comment: If you have a single `case`, an `if` statement would be clearer: `if field.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {}`.

Comment: Ended up with this, thanks for the pointers.

func fieldValue(field reflect.Value) string {
 format := "%v"
 if field.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
  if field.IsNil() {
   return "<nil>"
  }
  field = field.Elem()
 }
 if stringer, ok := field.Interface().(strfmt.DateTime); ok {
  return fmt.Sprintf(format, stringer.String())
 }

 return fmt.Sprintf(format, field.Interface())
}

Comment: @Peter what does prevent to have an empty switch: (`switch {` or `switch true {`) and the use `case field.Kind() == reflect.Ptr:` and `case field.IsNil:`? I know it doesn't apply in his case he needs a single case and you can do that easier with a single `if ...` but imagine they were two different cases.

Comment: @Adirio, nothing prevents you from doing that. I'm not sure what you're getting at. You'd still have to do the type assertion separately.

Comment: @Peter Oh, wait, the type assertion is above it. Can we use type assertions inside case statements? `case stringer, ok := field.Interface().(strfmt.DateTime); ok:`? Have never tried to do so. You could definetely create a function that returns `ok` but you will have to do a type cast inside (understanding type cast as a type assertion without the second output).

Comment: I will answer myself, no you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you could do is:

```
func isDateTime(field reflect.Value) bool {
    _, result := field.Interface().(strfmt.DateTime)
    return result
}

func fieldValue(field reflect.Value) string {
    switch {
    case isDateTime(field):
        return field.Interface().(strfmt.DateTime).String()
    case field.Kind() == reflect.Ptr:
        if field.IsNil() {
            return "<nil>"
        }
        field = field.Elem()
        fallthrough
    default:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%v", field.Interface())
    }
}
```

Comment: Like what you purpose, like the us of `fallthrough`

Comment: I would probably also remove the `fmt.Sprintf` from the first case. And yes, it is quite a good example of when `fallthrough` should be used.